# What does it  mean for a topological space $X$ to have a binary open cover?

Tags: general-topology

Does someone know what's meant by a *binary open cover* of a topological space $X$? I can't find this definition of binary open cover. Could someone who knows it tell me? Thanks ahead for any help:)

Comment: It might mean "open cover consisting of two open sets". What's the context?

Comment: Maybe you should give the context. If the definition is non-standard it is hard to guess. The word binary suggests that the cover consists of precisely two open sets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A binary open cover of a space $X$ is simply an open cover with exactly two members. For example, a $T_1$ space is normal iff every binary (= two-element) open cover of $X$ has a binary closed refinement. (This is an easy exercise.)